# How to calculate padding of linesize?

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

I am a newbie studying ffmpeg, and I found too few updated doc on the internet.

When I writing this:

```
av_image_fill_arrays(frame2->data, frame2->linesize, (const uint8_t *)NULL,
                                         frame->format, screenWidth, screenHeight,
                                         32);
sws_scale(videoScaleCtx, (const uint8_t **) frame->data,
                                      frame->linesize, 0,
                                      frame->height,
                                      dst, frame2->linesize);
```

It will simply display a black screen on bottom with 4 same small screen playing same time on top. I understand its padding mess with me, even though I get screen width with 2280, which shouldn't use padding since I have 32 bits cpu(frame2->linesize is 2304)?

Anyway, I desperately use this before scaling:

```
frame2->linesize[0] *= 4;
```

And this time everything looks normal! By right the padding is 4 times now which is not right?

Although sws_scale did two things: scale the pic and transform YUV420P to RGBA, but since the output pic shouldn't have padding, the des stride should simply be screen width * 4 = 9120, but now is 72 * 4 * 32 = 9216, how come?